# Trigger refresh of sites loaded from my Webserver

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Is it possible to trigger a refresh from backend to a specific URL?

Scenario:
Webserver

Backend to handle content of shown pages.

Pages where only shown on screens and has no user interactions.

Default content is loaded with ajax after a given interval.

Now I search for a solution to trigger a page refresh on the client from my backend to instantly show new content.

Is there a way to do that with symfony2?

Comment: See WebSockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API or trigger the refresh from AJAX.

Comment: Sorry for that bad title. Yes websockets is the right way. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use websockets to do that ([socket.io](http://automattic.github.io/socket.io/), or [ratchet](http://socketo.me/) with [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/js/) etc.). You can find many bundles implementing that functionality like:

https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle

https://github.com/phillies2k/ratchet-bundle

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Yes i thought about this too, but this is a huge refactoring of my application for this little feature. But yes this is the right way to do that.

Comment: *You must use websockets to do that* Not strictly, it's possible with AJAX too.

Comment: @A.L - can you explain how instantly show new content with ajax?

Comment: @malcolm I didn't see this was a requirement, I agree with you that AJAX can't work *instantly*, there will be a delay between each AJAX request. WebSocket doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per my knowledge there are few possibilities which you can try.

1. Ajax call (say 5 secs intervals)
2. Meta tag

PHP or server side language requires indication from client side about new data. So unless and until browser sends request to server, it remain in idle condition .

Comment: Hi thx for the answer. I make ajax calls to load my conten inside a interval but the question is how to triger a page/content reload outside from this interval :/ ?

Answer (score 0):

you can call your ajax function at regular intervals to update the content.

```
setInterval(function(){
                         ajaxCall();
                       },10000)
```

this will reload the content every 10 seconds

Comment: i update my content like this but the question is how to do a refresh outside from this interval like a manual triggering :/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store timestamp in your browser when client requested data A.

Then may u present another timestamp on api for shows when you last added content B.

In every interval you can decide by if B > A then refresh content sequence.
By this way your interval requests data size will be reduced.

But best solution is always websockets.

Comment: Yes i agree that websockets is the best solution for this.